# Cache HTTPS Static Assets

Tags: networking, cache, squid

I will be managing a network for an African College with limited Internet access. To help reduce network traffic and increase browsing speed, I was hoping to setup a Squid like caching server. However, with the move by more and more websites toward HTTPS for everything, and the major players already there, it becomes less effective an option, as the only non-HTTPS assets remaining which will continue to be cacheable will hardly be enough to make a noticeable decrease in network load.

However, I'm not sure I, nor the College, would be comfortable with terminating the SSL at the Squid server and forcing everyone to accept a wildcard SSL, just to try and cache a few more assets. Not only is this a pain, more importantly the security and liability issues are a road I don't want to go down.

The question I have is, are there any tools that will allow me to cache static assets for HTTPS pages like Google, Facebook, etc, without violating SSL. I'm worried the answer is probably no, and my googling seems to agree, but figured I'd ask before abandoning hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The point of using SSL is not just encrypting the data, so that noone could see your password, or validating that you are really logging in to your bank account and not some scammer. It is a privacy tool as well. When using SSL noone is able to see what kind of content you are transfering (although from IP they still may be able to guess which site). But from images/scripts/CSSs, the eavesdropper may be able to identify/guess much more, than just the site.

Besides making some kind of exceptions, or ways to work around this, could and probably would, lead to security issues.

There actually is a [movement](http://www.engadget.com/2015/05/01/mozilla-drops-http/) by Mozilla, that wants to stop supporting all non-encrpyted traffic in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

The best you could reasonably do would be to work with your internet providers to try and get a topologically close connection to a CDN, such as Akamai. (eg. have a Akamai node at your internet exchange.) Not sure how useful that would be, but considering that the bulk of commodity data is from things like video, it may be worthwhile.

You may also get some mileage out of setting client-side caching settings in browsers (eg. allowing browsers to cache more).